# Kohana view - loop over find_all()

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I am very new trying some kohana code and encountering first problem already :(

just to make it quick this is my model

```
<?php

class Model_Post extends ORM {

}
```

this is my controler

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Blog extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $posts = ORM::factory('Post')->find_all();
        $view = View::factory('blog/index')
            ->bind('posts', $posts); 
        $this->response->body($view);
    }
} // End Blog
```

and this is my view

```
<h2>My list of blog posts</h2>
<? foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <hr />
    <h4><?= $post->author ?></h4>
    <p><?= $post->body ?></p>
<?endforeach; ?>
```

Now i am getting an error

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: post
APPPATH\views\blog\index.php [ 4 ]
1 <h2>My list of blog posts</h2>
2 <? forech($posts as $post): ?>
3   <hr />
4   <h4><?= $post->author ?></h4>
5   <p><?= $post->body ?></p>
6 <?endforeach; ?>
```

I am going through [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YaZVbT9RMG8)

My resultset isnot empty as when i change my controller to

```
class Controller_Blog extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $posts = ORM::factory('Post')->find_all();
    //  $view = View::factory('blog/index')
    //      ->bind('posts', $posts); 
        $this->response->body($posts[0]->body);
    }
} // End Blog
```

it shows my first row

Comment: Just to be sure: is `forech` a typo in your post, or also in your code? should be `foreach`

Comment: sorry is was a typo there should be foreach but it's not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem ! I try to change the index.php like this :

```
<h2>My list of blog posts</h2>

<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <hr />
    <h4><?php echo $post->author ?></h4>
    <p><?php echo $post->body ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and it works for me !

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to recall your setup, and everything works fine on my installation of Kohana 3.2. You could try to check if there are posts, before the foreach?